# How to visualize the process of finding a solution in Gurobi

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

Working on an optimization problem using Gurobi, I have implemented my mathematical model in Python.

Is there a way to visualize how Gurobi performs the resolution step by step while checking all the constraints ?

I need to give a presentation to my colleagues (they do not understand maths) and give a proof regarding the way my mathematical model works.

I will be grateful if anyone would point me out to an approach.

Comment: That's very broad.There is probably nothing built-in and the stuff you can do using callbacks is limited too (imho; reverse-engineering would love access to all the internals :-D). The proof of your mathematical-model has nothing to do with Gurobi or Gurobi's solving-process. It's solely connected to the problem-definition like MIQP or whatever is used. In the open-source world (which won't help in your case) there is [GrUMPy](https://github.com/coin-or/GrUMPy)

Comment: @sascha The mathematical model is correct. I just wanted to try to see how the solver is getting the optimal solution. thanks for the link.

Comment: You could plot how the lower and upper bound on the objective converge over time. Eg [see here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/03/ggplot-and-miptrace.html). When there is no gap between the bounds you have a proven optimal solution.

Comment: Erwin is correct as always - in general it is really very hard to visualise what these sorts of solvers do, so we often just resort to looking at how the objective and bounds change over time as the B&B search process explores the search tree. However, if you know stuff about the structure of your problem and its solution then you *may* be able to invent something more directly meaningful; but it won't be simple to implement. I tried saving the best incumbent at each step, and then looking for changes from the previous solution to show how the details of the solution evolve. It got messy...

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick thank you for your comment :). I agree with you ;).

Comment: I don't want to put you off trying. If the problem is not too big, and you don't get too many incremental improvements in your solution, then you might get something useful. Of course, you may find that there are a large number of detail changes from one solution to the next. I have also looked at the Hamming distance between successive solutions as an interesting measure of how much of the detail of the solution is changing.

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick thank you for your suggestion on Hamming distance, nice idea by the way. You know, when we transform ''verbiage expressions'' into mathematical constraints it would be better to check that it does what we want and check the result.

Comment: Agreed. It is hugely valuable to reflect back from the mathematical abstractions to their interpretation in real world terms. Otherwise you can be doing a lot of work on stuff that looks OK as an abstraction but is meaningless in real life.

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick I was able to verify from the trace file returned by Gurobi so I am exactly getting the result expected from the mathematical abstraction. Thank you guys.